# Вывести список записей по выборке

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Я использую SQLite Базы данных
для даты и времени использую отдельные поля типа `Integer` в виде:

```
Year    /  month     / day
2016       9          13
```

Отправляю запрос:

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + DataBase.TABLE_NAME + "         where type='Все'"+
                                     " and month=9 and day<13  and day>6"
```

Результат ноль хотя есть записи.

Comment: А что это за " where type='Все'""? и там у вас до конца не дописана строка.

Comment: в SQLite Browser 'e использую именно это запрос. там дает результаты . но в Android studio не работает

Comment: Ecли вы хотите в Android в SQLite выбрать все записи, то не нужно писать "where type='Все'""

Comment: и у вас нету второго параметра, так что это должно выглядеть так: cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + DataBase.TABLE_NAME + "         where month=9 and day<13  and day>6",null);

Comment: Как вы узнаете, что `Результат ноль`? Что это вообще значит?

Comment: Lucky_girl у меня такой же запрос просто я забыл сюда написать второй параметр. А type это столбец типа String

Comment: metalurgus есть отдельный столбец money. нужно вычислить его сумму по найденным записям.    SQLiteBrowser возвращает 4 строку из этого запроса. А Android studio 0 строку

Comment: @ТемирланАбдуллаев 1) Проверьте есть ли у вас такая таблица в БД 2) Проверьте какие данные находятся в таблице 3) Проверьте название полей для которых вы пишите условие в rawQuery

Answer (score 1):

Для начала нужно правильно написать запись в db.rawQuery(), а именно указать второй параметр:

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + DataBase.TABLE_NAME + " where month=9 and day<13 and day>6",null);
```

Дальше нужно проверить:

1) есть ли таблица в БД для которой вы делаете выборку
2) Проверить какие данные находятся в таблице
3) Проверить название полей для которых вы пишите условие в `rawQuery`

Answer (score 0):

@Lucky_girl спасибо. Решил проблему. Вначале сохранил столбцов как String. В Телефоне эти записи сохранились. А потом я решил использовать Integer но не очистил таблицу. Запрос искал не по значению а String.Length  Поэтому и запрос вернул 0 строк.